# Jquery renders in Safari but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, safari

I am using the following code, it renders perfectly in Safari but not in Chrome. I am seeing no errors in the console in Chrome.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>



<!--http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/ -->


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('inside function');
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Active Users',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Users who visited on more than 2 days in the last 30 days',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["11/09/2016","12/09/2016","13/09/2016","14/09/2016","15/09/2016","16/09/2016","17/09/2016","18/09/2016","19/09/2016","20/09/2016","21/09/2016","22/09/2016",] //insert date here
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percent (%)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Monthly Active Users',
            data: [
            4.2359074617139,4.3266102797658,4.3492372606297,4.3000323310702,4.297253634895,4.1612903225806,4.1867954911433,4.3338683788122,4.3089690392595,4.3795620437956,4.3037974683544,4.294284812125,]
        }]
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What seems wrong in Chrome? Screenshot? Or please provide a demo link.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perfectly fine working snippet

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>



<!--http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/ -->


<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('inside function');
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Active Users',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Users who visited on more than 2 days in the last 30 days',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["11/09/2016","12/09/2016","13/09/2016","14/09/2016","15/09/2016","16/09/2016","17/09/2016","18/09/2016","19/09/2016","20/09/2016","21/09/2016","22/09/2016",] //insert date here
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percent (%)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Monthly Active Users',
            data: [
            4.2359074617139,4.3266102797658,4.3492372606297,4.3000323310702,4.297253634895,4.1612903225806,4.1867954911433,4.3338683788122,4.3089690392595,4.3795620437956,4.3037974683544,4.294284812125,]
        }]
    });
});
</script>
```

with your code that works on Chrome. Could you maybe provide more details about how you're running this and if there are any warnings in the console (not errors)

Answer (score 0):

I have just run the code in chrome and it renders just fine. I am using chrome version Version 52.0.2743.116 m.

[image]

Comment: Yes it is working in chrome..this should be the comment not the answer

Comment: i dd not have enough permissions earlier to add a comment. I am new to stackoverflow and just a few seconds ago one of my answers was upvoted, so now able to comment. Also I had to provide a image just to give a view of rendered image and the console.